# Express Redirect to Reload the Webpage Does Nothing, Using Pug for Views

Tags: express, redirect, routes, pug

I have a function in express that updates a user in the database. The current url where this function is run, is at `localhost:3000/users/specuser?key=<MY USER'S KEY HERE>`. When I update the user in the database, the webpage should change to load the new db value (which is accessed in the view). I tried this code at the end of the function to try to reload the page.

```
res.redirect(302, '/users/specuser?key=<MY USER'S KEY HERE>');
return;
```

But the page doesn't reload. I'm assuming that's because express sees the same url that the user is currently navigated to and ignores it? How do I reload the page so that the view sees the new user data and changes?

It's worth noting that when I change the end of this function to:

```
res.redirect(302, '/');
return;
```

The website does navigate to the root directory

It might also be worth noting that my views are written in pug js.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in the client side. In my pug view I have a script tag `script(type='module' src='/javascripts/specuserexists.bundle.js')` which links to a webpack compilation of a simple js file where my function is run that called the update to the user. At the end of this update the user function, I added `location.reload();` and then it worked.